# How to deal with C++ header file #include errors in VS Code on Mac?

Tags: c++, clang, visual-studio-code

VS Code on my Mac yields **#include errors** for **header files** and **third-party libraries** (*wxWidgets* in this case). I read everything I could find, adjusted "includePath" settings in "c_cpp_properties.json", but nothing helps.

Header files are located in the same folder as .cpp files ("/src/"). The project builds and runs nicely, but VS Code yields #include errors and error squiggles cover my entire project.

Below is the screenshot and a JSON file with VS Code settings.

[#include error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdINX.png)

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.5.1/include/wx-3.0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Please help me straighten this out.

————— **UPDATE** —————

I was recommended to use the following settings in *c_cpp_properties.json*:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-osx/include",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.5/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

*Header file* #include errors are gone, but the *third-party library* ("WX") errors persist. In the JSON above, there is the line "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-osx/include" written in the "includePath".

This is the [**vcpkg**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) package which helps install third-party libraries easily.

After installing **vcpkg**, I installed *wxWidgets* via **vcpkg**, but the library isn't linking in VS Code (builds just fine though) and I get error squiggles as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: see squiggles – the library is an alien object for VS Code :(]

Could you please explain how to straighten it out?

Comment: Unrelated. Is this a default color scheme?

Comment: I had similar problems with `C++ Intellisense` on Linux in combination with CMake Projects. I switched to clangd due to that and deactivated `C++ Intellisense`. The compiler uses the settings provided by CMake, so it compiles fine, but the plugins that give live feedback, need to get that information too, which is e.g. done by reading the `compile_commands.json` or the `c_cpp_properties.json`, but I'm not sure where and why this sometimes fails in case of  `C++ Intellisense` . But `clangd` also has it's problems if you don't build your code with clang.

Comment: @Evg, no, it's called "Oceanic Next Bimbo"

Comment: Thank you, @t.niese

Comment: One thing I see is that you choose `clang 11` as Kit for CMake but in the settings you have `"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++"` maybe that's what is causing the problem. You could also check the "Output" tab in VSCode and there the different output, maybe one of those gives a clue about what is wrong.

Comment: @t.niese, yeah, the choice is restricted to clang 10.0.0 and 11.0.0, unfortunately...

Comment: Also take a look at [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the problem was in several environment variables in **defs.h** file of WxWidgets library. To make VS Code recognize them on my system (OS X 10.14 Mojave), I had to add **"defines"** in the **c_cpp_properties.json** file in the following way:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
                "/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/**",
                "/usr/local/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.1",
                "/usr/local/lib/wx/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "WX_PRECOMP",
                "__WXOSX_COCOA__",
                "_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=1"                
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-9",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This solution is valid for Mac only. If you experience the same errors with includes or should you have class name squiggles on a different operating system, please find properties for **c_cpp_properties.json** file in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/huckor/wxwidgets-vscode/blob/master/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json).

Answer (score 2):

On the `includePath` property add `**` to the end of your directories path:

```
...
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.5.1/include/wx-3.0/**"
 ],
```

You can look form more details about `c_cpp_properties.json` on the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)

Comment: Thank you, @jpuriol. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. Instead, there might be a problem with WxWidgets library built on my Mac :(